# in dot net core razor pages - how do you default a dropdown choice on a create page?

Tags: asp.net-core, parent-child, razor-pages

I current have parent page that properly navigates to a different child page. The Child page has the stand grid of child records- AND it also has 'Create' link to add a new child record.

Under standard Entity Framework Scaffolding the 'Create' page has standard html'dropdown' lists for the fields that are linked to 'lookup' values.

Below are some screen shots:

[image: Parent Screen]

The Position Details link navigates to the child records:
[image: child grid]

The Create New Link brings up the standard scaffolded create page:
[image]

The PositionId field shows the full list of choices for parent lookup -rather  than bringing in parent key default.

Here is code for create page:

[image: cshtml]

[image: cs]

For the create page **my question is- how can I default that value of PositionID/PositionNbr to be what it would be for all the existing child records on the previous grid page?** This should be a standard child record create scenario- where parent key is prepopulated

I am not finding a whole lot of good examples on a google search for how to prepopulate the parent foreign key in the child records -particularly when the creation is on a separate create page.

Hope my question is making sense- thanks in advance ...

Modified- here is code as code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using ThePositionerRazor2.Models;

namespace ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PositionDetail
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ThePositionerRazor2.Models.WorkManagerV4Context _context;

        public CreateModel(ThePositionerRazor2.Models.WorkManagerV4Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
        ViewData["ImportanceId"] = new SelectList(_context.Imp, "ImportanceId", "ImportanceId");
        ViewData["Knowdepth"] = new SelectList(_context.Knowdep, "DepthId", "DepthId");
        ViewData["PositionId"] = new SelectList(_context.Possummary, "PositionId", "PositionNbr");
        ViewData["TimeSpent"] = new SelectList(_context.Timescale, "TimevalId", "TimevalId");
        ViewData["Workitem"] = new SelectList(_context.Workhier, "Workitemid", "Workitemid");
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Posdetail Posdetail { get; set; }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.Posdetail.Add(Posdetail);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
    @page
@model ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PositionDetail.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Posdetail</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.PositionId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.PositionId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PositionId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Workitem" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.Workitem" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Workitem"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.TimeSpent" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.TimeSpent" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TimeSpent"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.ImportanceId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.ImportanceId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ImportanceId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.TimeNrmz" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.TimeNrmz" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.TimeNrmz" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Knowdepth" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.Knowdepth" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Knowdepth"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Need" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Need" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Need" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.TimeCalc" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.TimeCalc" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.TimeCalc" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Postskval" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Postskval" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Postskval" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Ftetime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Ftetime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Ftetime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Ftesal" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Ftesal" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Ftesal" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Lastupdated" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Lastupdated" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Lastupdated" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

addtional info:

The relevant models

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ThePositionerRazor2.Models
{
    public partial class Possummary
    {
        public Possummary()
        {
            Posdetail = new HashSet<Posdetail>();
        }

        public int PositionId { get; set; }
        public string PositionNbr { get; set; }
        public string WorkTitle { get; set; }
        public string Purpose { get; set; }
        public double? JobValue { get; set; }
        public double? TimeTotal { get; set; }
        public double? Fte { get; set; }
        public double? Salary { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Lastupdated { get; set; }
        public string JobFamily { get; set; }
        public int? DescriptionTypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual Descriptiontype DescriptionType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Posdetail> Posdetail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ThePositionerRazor2.Models
{
    public partial class Posdetail
    {
        public int PosdetailId { get; set; }
        public int PositionId { get; set; }
        public int Workitem { get; set; }
        public int? TimeSpent { get; set; }
        public int? ImportanceId { get; set; }
        public double? TimeNrmz { get; set; }
        public int? Knowdepth { get; set; }
        public int? Need { get; set; }
        public int? TimeCalc { get; set; }
        public double? Postskval { get; set; }
        public double? Ftetime { get; set; }
        public double? Ftesal { get; set; }
        public DateTime Lastupdated { get; set; }

        public virtual Imp Importance { get; set; }
        public virtual Knowdep KnowdepthNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Possummary Position { get; set; }
        public virtual Timescale TimeSpentNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Workhier WorkitemNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly do not post code as screenshot it makes it difficult to help you. It is not clear what are the values `ViewBag.ImportanceId` and `ViewBag.PositionId` the naming tells they are simply an `Id` value, but they are assigned to `asp-items` list, so are they list of items or just an Id?

Comment: If you want to set the selected item in a select list, you assign the selected value to the `asp-for` attribute: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists#setting-selected-items. As an aside, you should avoid using `ViewData` anywhere except the layout page: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/viewdata

Comment: Hi -sorry for screenshots instead of code-wont do that again.. The ViewBags are a list of items. With this being a 'Create Page' you are presented with the entire list of items and by default- it defaults to the first entry. On an equivalent edit page it of course defaults to the current value. The PositionId is the foreign key for parent. Since this create page is for the child record it would be nice to have it default to the parent 'foreign' key  rather than having to type it in each time

Comment: I'll take a look at those learn razor pages links- thanks

Comment: Hi @LyndonSundmark,could you please share your model desgin?It would be more helpful to resolve your issue.

Comment: i got half way there. by adding an 'overload'? to the viewdata for positionid  ViewData["PositionId"] = new SelectList(_context.Possummary, "PositionId", "PositionNbr",ID);
          I added the ID to the selectlist. I just need to figure out how to pass that ID in as a parameter from the index page before it to the create page OnGet. Hardcoding the ID in the page renders as its supposed to defaulting the value of ID  when the page is loaded

Comment: models added to info above- thanks Rena

Comment: Ths index page does have that field on the page in the grid (hidden -obviously for existing child records). Its how to pass that as the default to the create page

Comment: @MikeBrind - I think the  ViewData was auto generated from entity framework scaffolding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmation of your requirement:

In your main Index page,you have a List `Possummary`.When you click the `Details` link,it will display the details of list `Posdetail` which belongs to the **Possummary** you choose in `Details` page.Then you click the `Create` link, it will display the **Possummary**'s PositionId which you choose at the begining in `Create` page.

To meet your requirement:

You could pass the `PositionId` in the `Create` link.Then set the default selected value for selectlist by this `PositionId`:

```
public IActionResult OnGet(int PositionID)
{
    ViewData["ImportanceId"] = new SelectList(_context.Imp, "ImportanceId", "ImportanceId");
    ViewData["Knowdepth"] = new SelectList(_context.Knowdep, "DepthId", "DepthId");

    //change here....
    ViewData["PositionId"] = new SelectList(_context.Possummary, "PositionId", "PositionNbr", PositionID);
    ViewData["TimeSpent"] = new SelectList(_context.Timescale, "TimevalId", "TimevalId");
    ViewData["Workitem"] = new SelectList(_context.Workhier, "Workitemid", "Workitemid");
    return Page();
}
```

The whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class Possummary
{
    public Possummary()
    {
        Posdetail = new HashSet<Posdetail>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public string PositionNbr { get; set; }
    public string WorkTitle { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }
    public double? JobValue { get; set; }
    public double? TimeTotal { get; set; }
    public double? Fte { get; set; }
    public double? Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Lastupdated { get; set; }
    public string JobFamily { get; set; }
    public int? DescriptionTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Descriptiontype DescriptionType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Posdetail> Posdetail { get; set; }
}
public class Descriptiontype
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Posdetail
{
    public int PosdetailId { get; set; }
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public int Workitem { get; set; }
    public int? TimeSpent { get; set; }
    public int? ImportanceId { get; set; }
    public double? TimeNrmz { get; set; }
    public int? Knowdepth { get; set; }
    public int? Need { get; set; }
    public int? TimeCalc { get; set; }
    public double? Postskval { get; set; }
    public double? Ftetime { get; set; }
    public double? Ftesal { get; set; }
    public DateTime Lastupdated { get; set; }

    public virtual Imp Importance { get; set; }
    public virtual Knowdep KnowdepthNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Possummary Position { get; set; }
    public virtual Timescale TimeSpentNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Workhier WorkitemNavigation { get; set; }
}
public class Imp
{
    [Key]
    public int ImportanceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Knowdep
{
    [Key]
    public int DepthId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Timescale
{
    [Key]
    public int TimevalId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Workhier
{
    [Key]
    public int Workitemid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Possummarys/Index.cshtml**:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Possummary[0].PositionNbr)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Possummary[0].WorkTitle)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Possummary[0].Purpose)
            </th>
     
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.Possummary) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PositionNbr)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkTitle)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purpose)
            </td>          
            <td>
                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PositionId">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.PositionId">Details</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.PositionId">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
```

**Possummarys/Index.cshtml.cs:**

```
namespace RazorProj3_1.Pages.Possummarys
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RazorProj3_1Context _context;

        public IndexModel(RazorProj3_1Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Possummary> Possummary { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Possummary = await _context.Possummary.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**Possummarys/Details.cshtml:**

```
@page
@model DetailsModel
     

    //focus here...
    <a asp-page="/PositionDetail/Create" asp-route-PositionID="@Model.Posdetail[0].PositionId" >Create New</a>
<h1>Postition Detail</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Posdetail[0].Position)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Posdetail[0].WorkitemNavigation)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Posdetail[0].TimeNrmz)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Posdetail[0].Importance)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Posdetail[0].Lastupdated)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Posdetail)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position.PositionNbr)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkitemNavigation.Workitemid)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeNrmz)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImportanceId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lastupdated)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PosdetailId">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.PosdetailId">Details</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.PosdetailId">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Possummarys/Details.cshtml.cs:**

```
public class DetailsModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly RazorProj3_1Context _context;

    public DetailsModel(.RazorProj3_1Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<Posdetail> Posdetail { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {

        Posdetail = await _context.Posdetail.Include(p=>p.Position)
                            .Include(p=>p.WorkitemNavigation)
                            .Where(a=>a.PositionId==id).ToListAsync();

        return Page();
    }
}
```

**PositionDetail/Create.cshtml:**   (the same as what you provided)

```
@page
@model CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Posdetail</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.PositionId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.PositionId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PositionId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Workitem" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.Workitem" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Workitem"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.TimeSpent" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.TimeSpent" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TimeSpent"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.ImportanceId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.ImportanceId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ImportanceId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.TimeNrmz" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.TimeNrmz" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.TimeNrmz" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Knowdepth" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.Knowdepth" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Knowdepth"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Need" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Need" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Need" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.TimeCalc" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.TimeCalc" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.TimeCalc" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Postskval" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Postskval" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Postskval" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Ftetime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Ftetime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Ftetime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Ftesal" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Ftesal" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Ftesal" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Lastupdated" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Lastupdated" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Lastupdated" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**PositionDetail/Create.cshtml.cs:**

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly RazorProj3_1Context _context;

    public CreateModel(RazorProj3_1Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet(int PositionID)
    {
        ViewData["ImportanceId"] = new SelectList(_context.Imp, "ImportanceId", "ImportanceId");
        ViewData["Knowdepth"] = new SelectList(_context.Knowdep, "DepthId", "DepthId");

        //change here....
        ViewData["PositionId"] = new SelectList(_context.Possummary, "PositionId", "PositionNbr", PositionID);
        ViewData["TimeSpent"] = new SelectList(_context.Timescale, "TimevalId", "TimevalId");
        ViewData["Workitem"] = new SelectList(_context.Workhier, "Workitemid", "Workitemid");
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Posdetail Posdetail { get; set; }
   
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        //the same as yours...
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rena!  That worked. i had thought of using routing id on create- but just  hadnt done it before. It does now default to that value on the create page. I tried creating a record and when I hit the create button, i got another error which i am still tracking down the cause of- " ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index') ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PositionDetail.Pages_PositionDetail_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml

Comment: <a asp-page="/PositionDetail/Create" asp-route-PositionID="@Model.Posdetail[0].PositionId">Create New</a>

Comment: In further looking into it - the record saves successfully in the sql server database. If I comment out the  return RedirectTo Page("./Index"); then no error comes up on the browser on the create page. But the moment it navigates back to the index page that called it- it hangs on the above error.

Comment: In summary navigation down to the create page defaulting in the value of the parent foreign key works, the record saves , but the navigation out bombs with the coding for the 'create' asp-route-Id

Comment: Hi @LyndonSundmark,It seems you ask a new question when you create data in your OnPost method.Please post a **new thread** in StackOverflow to share the detailed code and explain your requirement clearly(Share the `PositionDetail/Index.cshtml` and backend code).And if my answer in this thread help you,please remember to **accept as answer**.Thanks.

Comment: accepted as answer- definitely! will start new thread as per your suggestion- thank you!